# Size of key is too large for DES encryption

Tags: php, encryption, des

I was given

```
string: exchanges
key: exchanges1234
```

and need to encrypt it with 64-bit DES encryption.
I try to use php to enrypt it.

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)
```

But it return

> PHP Warning:  mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm in

Why is it so?

Comment: I just want to note that security wise this does pretty much everything wrong. 1) DES is weak since its key size is too small 2) ECB mode is weak 3) No MAC 4) directly using a password as key. | This is barely stronger than ROT13

Answer (score 0):

"Size of key is too large for this algorithm" is because you're using too big of a key. :)

A 64-bit key means you need a 64-bit key. With 8 bits per byte, this means 64/8 = 8, so your key needs to be exactly 8 bytes long.

Comment: Mean need exactly 8 hexadecimal digits?

Comment: "A 64-bit key means you need a 64-bit key"

Comment: @Loïc DES encryption is a 64-bit encryption method with 56 bits and 8 control bits. So the key needs to be 64-bits to encrypt. Or in this case `$key`

Comment: @conandor no it doensn't have to be 8 hexadicimal digits you can use any character you want as long as it is 8 bytes.

Comment: @conandor 8 bytes correspond to 16 hex digits, since each hex digits corresponds to 4 bits.